# How to put in recursive form of cleaning duplicates in a linked list?

Tags: recursion, linked-list

This function "cleans" duplicates from a list linked

```
def clean (self):

    key_node = self._front

    while key_node is not None:
        # Loop through every node - compare each node with the rest
        previous = key_node
        current = key_node._next

        while current is not None:
            # Always search to the end of the list (may have > 1 duplicate)
            if current._value == key_node._value:
                # Remove the current node by connecting the node before it
                # to the node after it.
                previous._next = current._next
                self._count -= 1
            else:
                previous = current
            # Move to the _next node.
            current = current._next
        # Check for duplicates of the _next remaining node in the list
        key_node = key_node._next
    return
```

How would the recursive way for this function look like?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to turn your while loop into tail-recursion, but I guess that's not what you want.

I assume this self thing with _front and _count is an additional structure "holding" the list -- we can either pass it along (as below), or re-count the list members afterwards.
It might look like this:

```
    def clean(self)
      self._front = rec_clean(self._front, self)
      return

    def rec_clean(current,self)  
      if current is None:
         return None
         else:
          if member(current._value, current._next):
             self._count -= 1
             return rec_clean(current._next, self)
          else:
             current._next = rec_clean(current._next, self)
             return current

    def member(value, current)
      if current is None:
         return false
         else:
         if current._value == value
            return true
         else:
            return member(value, current._next)
```

Note that now you'll have only the last (wrt to list's links) occurrence of each value, so you might want to reverse the list afterwards.

As of re-counting the new "cleaned-up" list, you could do it with another recursive function:

```
     def length(current)
       if current is None:
          return 0
          else:
          return 1+length(current._next)
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

```
# ... is just a place holder token that can't be None
# as I can't write what I want, (self, key_node=self._front)
# as self isn't defined at this point!

def clean_recursive(self, key_node=...):

    if key_node is ...:
        key_node = self._front
    elif key_node is None:
        return

    previous = key_node
    current = key_node._next

    while current is not None:
        if current._value == key_node._value:
            # Same situation as when we started, clean
            # rest of list; toss current node & quit loop
            self.clean_recursive(current)
            previous._next = current._next
            self._count -= 1
            break

        previous = current
        current = current._next

    self.clean_recursive(key_node._next)  # check the 2nd, 3rd, etc. element
```

Simply call self.clean_recursive() to get it rolling, the argument is only used for the recursions.